# Implicit type coercion?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, newtype

I don't understand why this code typechecks:

```
error1 :: ErrorT String (ReaderT Int IO) Int
error1 = asks id
```

fyi, the `asks` has this type:

```
asks :: Monad m => (r -> a) -> ReaderT r m a
```

On the other hand, I'm able to understand, that this code typechecks:

```
reader1 :: ReaderT Int IO Int
reader1 = asks id
```

`id` has type `a -> a` and there is an instance of `Monad` for `IO`, so the compiler can infer the type. That's clear for me.

The `ErrorT` is newtype and [haskell spec](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#dx10-74004) states, (in the section about newtypes):

> ... it creates a distinct type that must be explicitly coerced to or
>   from the original type ...

According to my interpretation, I should be able to get the same type as in `error1` **only** explicitly, with some coercion similar to this:

```
reader2 :: ReaderT Int IO (Either String Int)
reader2 = fmap (\i -> Right i) reader1

error2 :: ErrorT String (ReaderT Int IO) Int
error2 = ErrorT reader2
```

But, apparently, since the `error1` typechecks just fine, there is some knowledge hidden from me. Can You help uncovering it for me?

The imports needed for running the example code:

```
import Control.Monad.Error (ErrorT(ErrorT))
import Control.Monad.Reader (ReaderT, asks)
```

Comment: The type you're giving for `asks` is the type from `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader`. However, in `Control.Monad.Reader`, `asks` has a more general type, namely `asks :: MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a`.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of `mtl`, then `Control.Monad.Reader.asks` has the type `MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `asks` is exported by two related modules with slightly different types. The version from `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` (part of the `transformers` package), has the type given in the question:

```
asks :: Monad m => (r -> a) -> ReaderT r m a
```

However, the version used seems to be the one in the `mtl` package, from the `Control.Monad.Reader` module, which has the following, more general, type:

```
asks :: MonadReader r m => (r -> a) -> m a
```

So the example definition

```
error1 :: ErrorT String (ReaderT Int IO) Int
error1 = asks id
```

means that

```
MonadReader Int (ErrorT String (ReaderT Int IO))
```

must hold.

Also defined by `mtl` are the following instances for `MonadReader`:

```
instance Monad m => MonadReader r (ReaderT r m)
instance (Error e, MonadReader r m) => MonadReader r (ErrorT e m)
```

With these, the constraint above reduces to

```
(Error String, Monad IO)
```

which both hold as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your answer is that the monadic functions like `asks`, `put`, `get`, `throwError`, etc. in the `mtl` package are written to automatically lift themselves depending on how the monad stack is evaluated.

For example, the following function:

```
foo = do a <- asks id
         if a < 0 then throwError "oops"
                  else return $ sqrt a
```

can have both of the types:

- ErrorT String (ReaderT Double m) Double
- ReaderT (ErrorT String m Double) Double

depending on the order in which `runReaderT` and `runErrorT` are run.

The most general type of this function is:

```
foo :: (MonadError [Char] m, MonadReader b m, Ord b, Floating b) => m b
```

which shows there is no a priori ordering to the monad layers.

In your example you gave a type signature which says that there is an ErrorT layer in your monad even though you didn't use the `throwError` function. That's just equivalent to adding the `MonadError [Char] m` constraint to the type signature.